# Calling Python in C++

Tags: python, c++, object, import, module

I'm learning C++, and in particular C interface to Python. Right now, my focus is on calling or importing python objects from C++ main program.

I've been studying the following link but couldn't understand some concepts. (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820116/Embedding-Python-program-in-a-C-Cplusplus-code)
Following is the sections of the tutorial that I can't understand fully.

My questions are:

1. calling of module:
   Is it correct for me to assume "CPyObject pModule = PyImport_Import(pName)" is doing this job?
2. importing of objects:

i. Is it correct for me to assume "CPyObject pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "getInteger")" is doing this job?

ii.If I want to import a dataframe from python to C++ as a CPyObject, how can I manipulate this object in C++. I'm asking because there is no equivalent object to dataframe in C++.
3) Is there anything else I need to do to make sure my Python module file is visible and callable to C++ ? Such as saving them in the same folder?

```
Consider the following Python program, stored in pyemb3.py:

def getInteger():

print('Python function getInteger() called')

c = 100*50/30

return c

Now we want to call the function getInteger() from the following C++ code and print the value returned this function. This is the client C++ code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <pyhelper.hpp>
    
int main()
     {
    CPyInstance hInstance;

    CPyObject pName = PyUnicode_FromString("pyemb3");
    CPyObject pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    if(pModule)
    {
        CPyObject pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "getInteger");
        if(pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            CPyObject pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);

            printf_s("C: getInteger() = %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR: function getInteger()\n");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("ERROR: Module not imported\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `100*50/30` is not an **integer**, it is a **float**.

to get an integer use integer division: `100*50//30`

If you are not sure about the returned type, you can use the `Py_TYPE` macro on `pValue` or just simply check for the type you are looking for with: [`PyLong_Check`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_Check) or [`PyLong_CheckExact`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_CheckExact)

**1:** if `PyImport_Import` does not return null then the import was successful and the module was already executed by the time the function returned.

**2:** The [`PyObject_GetAttrString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString) or the [`PyObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr) is the right way to get the imported module's objects.

**3:** Use these [flags](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html?highlight=py_debug#global-configuration-variables) to ensure Python is embedded. Use [`Py_SetPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html?highlight=py_debug#c.Py_SetPath) before `Py_Initialize` to add your module's path to `sys.path`.